# How to calculate when an areostationary satellite would be unable to talk to earth?

Tags: mars, artificial-satellite

Consider an areostationary (geostationary but for Mars) satellite that communicates to Earth. Since on some orbits, Earth would be behind Mars from the point of view of the satellite, I imagine that it wouldn't be able to directly communicate with Earth during those periods (without using a relay of some kind). I would like to know how I would generate a table of each time Earth is directly unreachable, with the duration of each outage? An example table would be appreciated if created for some subset of the 2070s.

Bonus points for more accurate answers, especially those that would be accurate up to 100 years in the future.

I've spent some time looking around for answers and playing in python with PyEphem but was unable to figure out how to do this. After more research it looks like this might be possible with spiceyPy using its [subpnt](https://spiceypy.readthedocs.io/en/main/remote_sensing.html#computing-sub-s-c-and-sub-solar-points-on-an-ellipsoid-and-a-dsk-subpts) method, but I'm way out of my depth when it comes to figuring out how to actually use that.